# HoloLens OS files access and Calibration data

Tags: hololens, calibration

I would like to know if can get access to the internal OS files in HoloLens and the data that is been generated during the callibration proccess.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that would be a **no**. Microsoft has kept most everything OS level off limits to developers. Are you looking to recreate the calibration process? Or is this for something else entirely?

If you are looking to recreate the calibration app, here is a GitHub link to a custom app used to calculate the IPD of the user by using a photograph.
https://github.com/alexdrenea/HoloLensIPD

Since all the calibration app is doing is basically calculating the distance between your eyes. Maybe you can find what you're looking for in there.